# Why are the share button and toolbar blue in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Here is the capture.
[image]

But the share button and toolbar look normal if I use another account.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Google is currently (March 2023) rolling out an upgrade to Google Sheets that includes cosmetic changes to the user interface. The upgrade reaches different users at different times.

See [Delivering a simpler user experience](https://workspace.google.com/blog/productivity-collaboration/more-flow-less-work-smart-canvas) at the Google Workspace Blog.